Terragrunt plan-all module download path wrong
I want to deploy my terraform modules in 3 stages due to dependencies. I don't want to define all the dependency/ies in the .hcl files of terragrunt.
In order to achieve this I am overhauling my directory structure. First, everything was in the same directory (i.e. tree /infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test). Now I've added a subdirectory like so:
tree /infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test/basis

├── appconfiguration
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── appinsights
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── identities
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── keyvault
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── loganalytics
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── networksecuritygroup
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── public-ip-addresses
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── resourcegroup
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── storageaccounts
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
└── subnets-azcli
    └── terragrunt.hcl

These files refer to the hcl files with the terragrunt configuration which is at this path: /infra-integratiehub/environments/_env
My modules exist in /infra-integratiehub/modules.
Here's a tree for further clarification:
/infra-integratiehub
├── environments
│   ├── _env (this has the terragrunt config files)
│   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── uva-test (/basis is the dir in which terragrunt -run-all is executed. With tree shown above)
├── modules (all the tf modules).

When I run terragrunt -run-all plan, it will try to download the modules necessary. The path should be /infra-integratiehub/modules/{modulename}.
Instead it is: /infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test/modules
This is (one of) the hcl config files contents:
terraform {
  source = "../../modules/appconfiguration"
}

locals {
  env_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))
} 

This is the error:
ERRO[0000] Module /infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test/basis/appconfiguration has finished with an error: downloading source url file:///infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test/modules/appconfiguration
1 error occurred:
        * stat /infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test/modules/appconfiguration: no such file or directory
  prefix=[/infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test/basis/appconfiguration] 

Why is the path to the modules formed as it is?

It seems like the origin of the problem lies in terragrunt using get_parent_terragrunt_dir and the value of this is /infra-integratiehub/environments/uva-test/basis. It probably uses this path because the /basis folder from wich the terragrunt run-all command is executed. In the original setup this went through withouth a hitch though. I just created an extra subfolder.

When I use the hard path reference, it works fine. But I don't want to do this because it should be dynamic, as it runs in a pipeline (eventually).

The origin of the issue is most likely related to the use of get_parent_terragrunt_dir. I reckon terragrunt uses this inexplicably.
I fixed it (changed it) to use the following:
  source =find_in_parent_folders("modules/{modulename}")

This looks for the folder and subfolder combinations in all the loaded files and does the trick.
